PySpark Dataframe API Partition by one table, Sort by field in another table
Thank you in advance for the help.
I'm using Databricks.  I'd like to convert this code that uses SQL to use the PySpark Dataframe API.
For record, we want to take the sum of the 3 most recent values, from 10 days in the past to 3 days in the past.
Example:

For person A on Date 25
Our window is from Date 15 - Date 22.
There are 4 records in that range:  Dates 15, 18, 19 and 22.
We take the last 3 dates in that range, which is dates 18, 19 and 22.
We take the sum of the values for those dates.

I am getting stuck where the Window uses different tables for Partitioning and Sorting.
In my SQL example, the Window function partitions using fields from t1, but sorts using fields from t2.
How do I convert the SQL code to use the PySpark Dataframe API?

Working Databricks code:
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('A',12,1),
        ('A',15,2),
        ('A',18,3),
        ('A',19,4),
        ('A',22,5),
        ('A',25,6),
        ('B',15,1),
        ('B',17,2),
        ('B',20,3)
    ],
    ["Person", "Date", "Value"]  # add your column names here
)

display(df)

df.createOrReplaceTempView("df_sql")

sql1 = '''
select t1.Person, t1.Date, t1.Value, t2.Value as Historical_values,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.Person, t1.Date ORDER BY t2.Date DESC) AS row_num
from df_sql t1 cross join df_sql t2
where t1.Person = t2.Person
    and t2.date >= t1.date - 10
    and t2.date <= t1.date - 3
qualify row_num <= 3
order by 1, 2
'''

sql2 = '''
select Person, Date, Value, sum(Historical_Values) as Historical_Values
from ({sql1})
group by 1,2,3
'''.format(sql1=sql1)

display(spark.sql(sql2))

Databricks output:

Thank you!!!!
